# Why my MATLAB2013 compiler doesn't have .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

[image]

There isn't a .NET assembly framework compiler.

How to add ?

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio or .Net SDK installed?

Comment: .NET used to be a separate package, it was only integrated into the MATLAB Compiler package fairly recently.

Comment: You can create a DLL in Matlab and then in c# use DllImport.  You will need to install the Matlab runtime library for 2013 for code to run.

Answer (score 1):

I download and install the MATLAB 2015, and it has .NET compiler.